# Scale down iframe (preview webpage)

Tags: html, iframe

How could I create a preview of a webpage? Using iframe, I could not scale down the contents of the page in order to create a nice looking overview.

The following fails

```
<iframe src="/mplahmplah#important_stuff" style="width:700px; height:900px; -moz-transform:scale(0.15, 0.15)" sandbox="" seamless scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Comment: Of course, `-moz-transform` will only work for Mozilla browsers...

Comment: The `style` on an `<iFrame>` is **for** the `<iFrame>`.  The contents of an `<iframe>` are rendered completely separately, and do **not** inherit the styles from the `<iframe>` in the same way that elements within an HTML document do.

Answer (score 1):

If the domain of the iframe and the container page is the same and you are using jQuery, try something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('iframe').on('load', function(){
        $(this).contents().find('body').css({'-webkit-transform':'scale(0.15, 0.15)', '-moz-transform':'scale(0.15, 0.15)'}); 
    });
});
```

The point is that you don't want to scale the iframe, you want to scale it's contents.

Comment: Nice idea. I tried it but unfortunately I does not work. I would like to display (and scale) all the elements under the div with `id="important_stuff"`.